# How to set the updatepanel as readonly when it's doing any operation?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have an Tab control inside the update panel. Whenever the update progress started I want to make that update panel as readonly. Once the update progress is done then I want to make it to it's normal state.

Any help?

Comment: Are you saying you want to disable the UpdatePanel while it is doing a postback, to prevent users from interfering with it during that time?

Comment: Yes. Either disable or readonly

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is position a transparent DIV over the content. For example if update is triggered by a Button, the sequence can go like this:

1. On Button's ClientClick event - position the DIV over content and set its display style to "block"
2. In server-side code generate a JavaScript command to set DIVs display style back to "None"

Comment: Then you may have to take a look at [UpdatePanel LifeCycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417(v=vs.100).aspx) for example you can show the Div at `beginRequest` event and hide it at `pageLoaded`